# TCP connect() Error code 113(No Router to host) - Linux C++

Tags: linux, tcp

How to troubleshoot when Errno code 113 (no router to host) occurs?

I have a Linux embedded device with a wifi module in Concurrent mode. I am currently encountering a problem that when the embedded device is connected to the A device, the embedded device obtains the IP of the A device through the "arp" command to set the addrinfo structure ( non-blocking). The Connect() function is performed through this addrinfo to complete the TCP handshake. At this time, there is a chance that Errno code 113 (no router to host) will occur continuously and cause the connection to fail. Device A and the embedded device confirm that there is no firewall setting. This question is intermittent. The error occurred for more than 5 minutes and then resumed, and it occurred again after a while.

Attach the relevant code

```
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
int rv;
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
bool SucessFlag = true;
static int failedtoconcnt[10];
static int StartRTC[10];
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;//ipv4 & ipv6
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;//tcp
cout << "Try to Connect IP: " << chIP << "Port "<< chPort << endl;
if (strlen(chIP) < 6)   return 2;

for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(chIP, chPort, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return -1;
    }
    void *addr;
    if (servinfo->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
      struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)servinfo->ai_addr;
      addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
      inet_ntop(servinfo->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof(ipstr));
    } else { // IPv6
      struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)servinfo->ai_addr;
      addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
      inet_ntop(servinfo->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
    }

    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd[id] = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("client: socket Error");
        continue;
    }

    if (sockfd[id] != 0){
        for(int i=0;i<MaxID;i++){
            if (ModTcpIPA->InvConnectID[i] == 1){
                if (sockfd[id] == sockfd[i+1] && id != i+1){
                    DC_DEBUG_NL("sockfd[%d]=%d", id, sockfd[id]);
                    DC_DEBUG_NL("sockfd[%d]=%d", i+1, sockfd[i+1]);
                    CloseAllSock();
                    SucessFlag = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fcntl(sockfd[id], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if (connect(sockfd[id], p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0)  break;
    sleep(1);
    printf("1errno: %2d\t%s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    if (connect(sockfd[id], p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0)  break;
    sleep(1);
    printf("2errno: %2d\t%s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    if (connect(sockfd[id], p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0)  break;
    sleep(1);
    printf("3errno: %2d\t%s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    if (connect(sockfd[id], p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0)  break;
    sleep(1);
    printf("4errno: %2d\t%s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
}
if (p == NULL) {
    DC_DEBUG_NL("client: failed to connect");
    fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
    close(sockfd[id]);
    return 1;
}
inet_ntop(p->ai_family, toget_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    if (SucessFlag == true){
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: I suppose your error is "No route to host" (no "r" at the end of "route"). Correct?

Answer (score 0):

What do you see when you type:

```
$ route
```

in your console on the machine where you want to run that software?

You should see something similar to the following:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway    Genmask   Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         1.2.3.4    0.0.0.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

The `default` destination (0.0.0.0) is what makes the routing work. A bit like magic. If no other IP matches, the default gets used to send the data and the Gateway is then responsible for further forwarding or handling the packets.

If none of your routes says `UG` under the **Flags** column, then you are missing the gateway altogether. If there is such a line, maybe the gateway IP is what's wrong.

If you have name resolution issues, try the `-n` command line option:

```
$ route -n
```

If that is not the issue, I would make sure that I get the correct IP address in the code by printing it out. That way you can see whether something's wrong in the code. I could not see anything wrong, although your code is difficult to read (it's good old C rather than C++... where are your classes? I have a project to do such things [here](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher) and it uses [another project](https://github.com/m2osw/libaddr) to handle IP addresses because it's such a mess!)